# How to pass an argument to the python interpreter (not to the python code) in VS code via launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to pass the "-q -X faulthandler" arguments to the python interpreter in VS code launch.json but I have not found a solution yet (args passes argument to the .py file).

So the command would look like this in the teminal:

python** -q -X faulthandler** main.py --arg1 --arg2

Thank you!

I've read the VS code documentation but I have not found any description for this.
I've tried to execute the python script in VS code with the following lauch.json options (neither worked):

1,
"type": "python **-q -X faulthander**",
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"request": "launch",
"program": "main.py",

2,
"type": "python",
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"request": "launch",
"program": "**- q -X faulthandler** main.py",

Comment: [*pythonArgs*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_pythonargs): Specifies arguments to pass to the Python interpreter using the syntax `"pythonArgs": ["<arg 1>", "<arg 2>",...]`.

Comment: Hi JialeDu! Thank you so much! I should have read the documentation twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_pythonargs), in *launch.json* you can add `pythonArgs` configuration to specify parameters for the interpreter.

Another way is to install the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, and then search for `Code-runner: Custom Command` in setting to customize the execution command.

[image]

Or add the following configuration directly in ***settings.json*** to have the same effect.

```json
    "code-runner.customCommand": "python $fileName",
```

After the configuration is complete, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Run: Cunstom Command`(***Ctrl + Alt + K***) to execute the code.

[image]

Comment: Hi.Thanks! I am testing it. In general I do not like that VS code does not properly show what is the command that is executed in its terminal so I can not see wether these arguments are really passed to the interpreter. I've found someone reporting a bug recently https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19810... so I tried with python.terminal.launchArgs fist. Unfortunately this does not seem to pass the params. (code stopped with no warnings/error but in the native terminal window I god a proper error message). So now I try with "pythonArgs": ["-q", "-X", "faulthandler"]. let's see..

Comment: The "pythonArgs": ["-q", "-X", "faulthandler"] works fine! Also VS code displays the error! Thanks once again!